# CentOS8 Virtualbox guest additions

Tags: centos, virtualbox

In VirtualBox CentOs8-Stream from scratch i can't install Additionnal Guest.

This is what i do

1. Create new VM CentOS8 Stream
2. in root **yum groupinstall "Development Tools"**
3. in root **yum install elfutils-libelf-devel**
4. I insert the guest additionnal (Devices > insert guest additionnal cd > Launch)

And i get this error:

**Building the modules for kernel 4.18.0-326.el8.x86_64
Look at /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log to find out what went wrong
modprobe vboxguest failed**

In this log i see:

```
Error building the module.
ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid
include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing
Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
```

I dont understand why?  because i just created the virtual machine and updated the kernel so i dont understand why it would be corrupted

Comment: Have you tried installing the kernel development package which is normally required to compile kernel modules? `dnf install kernel-devel` as it is not included in the "Development Tools" group.  Also, you should not need to install `elfutils-libelf-devel` separately as it is included in the "Development Tools" group.

Comment: When i try to `dnf install kernel-devel` it say that is it alreay installed, and `nothing to do`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found in this link https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20488#comment:4 there is a bug in version VBoxguestAddition1.26.

So I downloaded and installed **VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.27-146191.iso** and it works fine on my kernel-**4.18.0-326**.el8.x86_64 in  **VirtualBox 6.1.26** after a reboot.